# How to detect windows or doors in a picture?

Tags: c++, windows, image, detection

Which image processing techniques could be used to implement an application that detects windows and/or doors in pictures?

I'm looking for something that can be written in C++, using Open Source technologies.

The idea is to detect doors and/or windows in pictures taken from the inside, right across from them.

Comment: Never used it myself but I see a lot of questions about it here in SO: http://opencv.org/

Answer (score 2):

The OpenCV Library mentioned by @user2225104 is a good starting point in my opinion.
I think you should have a look to [Hough Line Transform](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_lines/hough_lines.html) which can be used to detect straight lines (which should apply to doors and windows). As a preprocessing step, some kind of edge detection should be applied (as mentioned in the linked page), which could be e.g. the [Canny Edge Detector](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/canny_detector/canny_detector.html).

Comment: Yes indeed these functions are very useful to manually find the doors and the windows but i'm looking for something that could work automatically for a large type of pictures with different brightness and contrast